# Casting Dynamic to an other class

Tags: haxe

I would like to know if that's possible to cast a Dynamic to an other class (partially or totally)

For example, this code breaks :

```
class Test {
    public function new() {}
    public var id: String;
}

class Main {
    public static function main() {
        var x:Dynamic = JsonParser.parse("{\"id\":\"sdfkjsdflk\"}");
        var t:Test = cast(x, Test);
    }
}
```

with the following message

> Class cast error

However, my "Test" class has an "id" field like the dynamic object. (That's an example, my use case is more complexe than that ^^)

So, I don't understand how to get an object from my Dynamic one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't exactly casting a dynamic to a class instance but may accomplish the same thing:

- create an empty instance of the class with `Type.createEmptyInstance`
- set all of the fields from the Dynamic object on the new class instance using `Reflect`

Example:

```
import haxe.Json;


class Test {
    public function new() {}
    public var id: String;
}

class Main {
    public static function main() {
        var x:Dynamic = Json.parse("{\"id\":\"sdfkjsdflk\"}");
        var t:Test = Type.createEmptyInstance(Test);
        for (field in Type.getInstanceFields(Test))
            if (Reflect.hasField(x, field))
                Reflect.setProperty(t, field, Reflect.getProperty(x, field));

        trace(t.id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [typedef](http://haxe.org/manual/type-system-typedef.html)

```
typedef Test = {
    public var id: String;
}

class Main {
    public static function main() {
        var t:Test = JsonParser.parse("{\"id\":\"sdfkjsdflk\"}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, my question is about casting dynamic to a class. The written code is just an example, I just want to know if that's possible :) Thank you

Comment: When I'm doing this, Type.getClassName(Type.getClass(t)) returns null. Is that normal ?

Comment: Yes, for unsafe cast. More info here http://haxe.org/manual/expression-cast-unsafe.html

Answer (score 1):

`Json.parse` returns anonymous structure(implementation platform dependent), typed as Dynamic. There isn't a single chance to cast it to anything but Dynamic, unless `Json.parse` returns Int, Float or String, which some parsers permit, but which isn't actually permitted by JSON specification.

That is this way because, the operation of casting doesn't check what fields some object have. Operation of casting only checks if the object is an instance of class you are casting to. Obviously, anonymous structure can't be an instance of any class(inside haxe abstractions at least).

However, the right way to perform the thing you seem to be trying to perform is the way stated by @Ben Morris, in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27330402/casting-dynamic-to-an-other-class/#27333773).